# サーバーとの通信で Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Length"

Tags: javascript, android, monaca

monaca の開発環境でAndroidのアプリを作っています。
下記のようなロジックで外部のサーバーから情報を取得しようとしているのですが、
Refused to get unsafe header "Content-Length"
というエラーが返ってきます。どうすれば回避できるのでしょうか？
アクセスするサーバーの.htaccess ファイル等は編集可能です。
よろしくお願いします。

```
function funcDbGet(){
    var url = 'https://---省略---';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url,true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(req.status === 200) {
                console.log("200"+req.responseText);
            }
            else {
                console.log("err"+req.status);
                console.log(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CORSの仕組みによって拒否されてるっぽいですね。
FAQにある対応をしてみたらどうでしょうか。

引用元 https://docs.monaca.io/ja/faq/environment/

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ( CORS ) を有効にしたいのですが。
>
> 次のヘッダーを CORS ( Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ) のレスポンスに追加すれば、CORS を有効にできます。
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> 上記に付け加え、アプリまたはデバッガー側から外部の URL へのアクセスを許可する場合には、次のいずれかの設定を行います。
>
> ```
> Monaca IDE 上で設定を行う場合 : iOS の設定 と Android の設定 を参照のこと。
> 設定ファイル上で設定を行う場合 : iOS の設定 と Android の設定 を参照のこと。
> ```

Comment: ヘッダーに追加しましたがエラーは変わらないです。ただエラーが出ているのにデータが受信できている事がわかりました。「警告」なのかな